# What should one do with hot coffee during a meal?

Tags: halacha, blessing, bread, hamotzi-beracha

Say one finished a meal consisting of bread and poured oneself a hot cup of coffee. This person wants to get up and go to a different room or outside but needs to bench for the bread.

Do you say Bikat Hamazon and then a shehakol on the coffee afterwards? Or do you wait to finish the coffee--wherever you end up--and then say birkat hamazon?

Comment: Bentch on a kos.